# Confused with Standard definition of Truncate statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am having fair amount of Experience with MSSQL server.We have a database migration from MYSQL to SQL server.I never have worked with MYSQL,so i was going through differences using this [link](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#bulk-truncate_table).

In one place on the page,Below is the definition of Truncate..

> The SQL standard defines the TRUNCATE TABLE tablename statement (optional feature ID F200, new in SQL:2008) as:
>   Delete all rows of a base table without causing any triggered action.
>
> Unfortunately, the standard doesn't specify
>   1. whether TRUNCATE TABLE should be allowed in a transaction involving other statements, or not
>    2. whether TRUNCATE TABLE should imply an immediate COMMIT, or not

For SQL server ,the page says

> Follows the standard.
>
> In MSSQL, TRUNCATE TABLE is allowed in a transaction involving other operations, and TRUNCATE TABLE does not imply an immediate COMMIT operation.

For MYSQL,the page says

> MySQL has a TRUNCATE TABLE statement, but it doesn't always follow the standard.
>
> Note that in some cases, MySQL's truncate command is really the equivalent of an unrestricted DELETE command (i.e.: potentially slow and trigger-invoking). Its behaviour depends on which storage engine the table is managed by.
>
> When using InnoDB (transaction safe) tables, TRUNCATE TABLE is allowed in a transaction involving other operations, however TRUNCATE TABLE implies an immediate COMMIT operation.

In SQLServer,when you truncate a table
1.The operation may be minimally logged
2.only page deallocations happen and are logged in transaction log

So my question is:
1.What does below wording in standard means  and how SQL server is following standard and MYSQL is not.

> whether TRUNCATE TABLE should imply an immediate COMMIT, or not

Comment: Just to give you idea about truncate table its DDL query which drop and recreate table (not deleting data). its directly dropping the table and recreating it. you cant execute DDL in transaction block

Comment: See Devart's [page](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/docs/index.html?truncate-table.htm) on `TRUNCATE` tables and Safari's [manual](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-reference-manual/0596002653/ch07s05.html). The difference depends on the type of tables you are dealing with. `InnoDB` tables are ACID-based, but in either case `TRUNCATE` is not transaction safe and will NOT trigger `DELETE` triggers.

Honestly, `TRUNCATE` is for when you do not care about the data .`DELETE` is business friendly in case a mistake or malicious event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the links from Clifton_h and answers for this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/why-use-both-truncate-and-drop/7685#7685)...

My question was what does this wording meant

> whether TRUNCATE TABLE should imply an immediate COMMIT, or not

This all boils down to whether you can rollback the truncate or not..

**For MYSQL and Oracle:**
You cant rollback a truncate,since those DBMS does apply implicit commits after transaction and this will be rolled back only in case of error,but user cant do this

**For SQL server:**
You can rollback a truncate ,since immediate commits are not applied..